# xCode Distribution compile error {iPhone SDK}

Tags: iphone, xcode

when i want compile my app with the Distribution or Release method i get 140 ERRORS, i am using facebook connect on my app , and the path is right [my errors refer to fbconnect] , xcode runs my app fine on the debug !!!!!!! what's the problem ?

[alt text http://freezpic.com/pics/c23582edf48b5cf8b0115f98800a0abf.jpg](http://freezpic.com/pics/c23582edf48b5cf8b0115f98800a0abf.jpg)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably did not set the path for Distribution. Look at the differences between your Distribution and your Debug configurations.